# SQL query to find empty nodes in a tree structure table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm developing an Android application that stores some of its data as a tree like structure in an SQLite table.

As an example, the relevant part of the table has the following structure:

| id | name | type | depth | parentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | node | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2 | node | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | node | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | node | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | node | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 6 | node | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | 7 | node | 3 | 4 |
| 8 | 8 | node | 3 | 6 |
| 9 | ** | data | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | ** | data | 2 | 2 |
| 11 | ** | data | 3 | 4 |
| 12 | ** | data | 3 | 5 |

The following image represents the same data of the table:

[image: Tree structure in the table]

The question is: How can I get all the nodes (`type = node`) that have no `data` structures below them? In the example the result would be nodes 6, 7 and 8 which are colored green in the tree.

For now, I'm only able to get empty nodes on the deepest part of the tree with the following query:

```
SELECT id
FROM treeTable
WHERE type = 'node'
    AND id NOT IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT parentId
        FROM treeTable
        WHERE parentId IS NOT NULL)
```

My problem is with that node number 6. It should be returned in the query but, as it appears as a parent of another node I don't know how to filter it out. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: This question is discussed in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419392/what-is-the-best-practice-for-following-up-after-your-question-has-been-answered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could use recursion to find the data nodes within each 'node' node. The first one is for SqlServer:

```
with treeTable as (
select *
from (values 
 (1,'1','node',0,null)
,(2,'2','node',1,1)
,(3,'3','node',1,1)
,(4,'4','node',2,2)
,(5,'5','node',2,3)
,(6,'6','node',2,3)
,(7,'7','node',3,4)
,(8,'8','node',3,6)
,(9,'**','data',2,2)
,(10,'**','data',2,2)
,(11,'**','data',3,4)
,(12,'**','data',3,5)
) T(id, name,   type,   depth,  parentId)
),
Hry as (
 SELECT StartNode=TN.id, ThisNode=TN.id, TN.name, tn.type, tn.depth, L=0
 FROM treeTable TN
 union all
 SELECT StartNode=H.StartNode, ThisNode=TN.id, TN.name, TN.type, TN.depth, L=L+1
 FROM treeTable TN
      inner join 
      Hry H
      on H.ThisNode=TN.ParentId
)
/* Now repeat for each 'node' node: recursively traverse each sub-tree and see if there are data nodes underneath */
select T.id
from treeTable T
     left join
     Hry H
     on T.id=H.StartNode
     and H.type='data'
where T.type='node'
and H.StartNode is null
```

For Sqlite

```
with treeTable as (
    select  1 as id, '1'as name,'node' as type,0 as depth ,null as parentID union all
    select  2 as id, '2'as name,'node' as type,1 as depth ,   1 as parentID union all
    select  3 as id, '3'as name,'node' as type,1 as depth ,   1 as parentID union all
    select  4 as id, '4'as name,'node' as type,2 as depth ,   2 as parentID union all
    select  5 as id, '5'as name,'node' as type,2 as depth ,   3 as parentID union all
    select  6 as id, '6'as name,'node' as type,2 as depth ,   3 as parentID union all
    select  7 as id, '7'as name,'node' as type,3 as depth ,   4 as parentID union all
    select  8 as id, '8'as name,'node' as type,3 as depth ,   6 as parentID union all
    select  9 as id,'**'as name,'data' as type,2 as depth ,   2 as parentID union all
    select 10 as id,'**'as name,'data' as type,2 as depth ,   2 as parentID union all
    select 11 as id,'**'as name,'data' as type,3 as depth ,   4 as parentID union all
    select 12 as id,'**'as name,'data' as type,3 as depth ,   5 as parentID 
),
Hry as (
 SELECT TN.id as StartNode, TN.id as ThisNode, TN.name, tn.type, tn.depth, 0 as L
 FROM treeTable TN
 union all
 SELECT H.StartNode as StartNode, TN.id as ThisNode, TN.name, TN.type, TN.depth, L+1 as L
 FROM treeTable TN
      inner join 
      Hry H
      on H.ThisNode=TN.ParentId
)
/* Now repeat for each 'node' node: recursively traverse each sub-tree and see if there are data nodes underneath */
select T.id
from treeTable T
     left join
     Hry H
     on T.id=H.StartNode
     and H.type='data'
where T.type='node'
and H.StartNode is null
```

Answer (score 4):

After some research based on the @tinazmu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72989393/3576968), I finally came up with a query that seems to be working fine for my case in SQLite.

```sql
WITH AncestryTree AS (
    SELECT id, parentId, type
    FROM Tree
    WHERE parentId IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.id, AT.parentId, T.type
    FROM AncestryTree AT
        JOIN Tree T ON AT.id = T.parentId
)

SELECT id
FROM Tree
WHERE type = 'node'
    AND id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT parentId
        FROM AncestryTree
        WHERE type = 'data'
    )
```

The query can be tested in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9QSJzpP6D7NTgR8U1BxHQ8/0), but it'd be great if someone pointed out any flaws or optimizations to this query.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not necessary